# List collection addRange multiple items

Tags: c#

Till now i am using the code below for adding new items in list.

```
 mItems.Add(new TableItemsClass() { Description = sqlReader["Name"].ToString(),InventoryTransTempID = Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["InventoryTransTempID"]) });
```

How can I use the same method for using the `AddRange`?

```
 mItems.AddRange(new TableItemsClass() { Description = sqlReader["Name"].ToString(),InventoryTransTempID = Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["InventoryTransTempID"]) });
```

With the code above I am taking the following error:

`CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'WiOrderAndroid.TableItemsClass
to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WiOrderAndroid.TableItemsClass>`

Comment: Because you are only adding one element where an IEnumerable is expected.

Comment: Why would you want to use `AddRange` when you're only adding one element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddRange` expects IEnumerable as argument, but you are passing T. To fix it just pass it a list:

```
mItems.AddRange(
    new List<TableItemsClass> 
    { 
        new TableItemsClass() 
        { 
          Description = "descr",
          InventoryTransTempID == 1
        },
        new TableItemsClass() 
        { 
           Description = "descr",
           InventoryTransTempID == 2
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`AddRange` takes an `IEnumerable`, not a single element. One way to handle such scenarios is to wrap your item in an array:

```
mItems.AddRange(new TableItemsClass[] {new TableItemsClass() { Description = sqlReader["Name"].ToString(),InventoryTransTempID = Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["InventoryTransTempID"]) }});
```

Answer (score 0):

AddRange is used to add more than one item of Enumerable type. `new TableItemsClass()` is one object. So `Add` will work. If you have a collection of these objects like a `List<TableItemsClass>()` then you can use `AddRange()` Method